Prop is usable in template but not in script
I'm a little confused as I've got a prop called filterData with an array being sent from the parent app to a child app, and it both shows in the Vue inspector with the populated array:

and it also works fine populating the page with products when I run it as a v-for loop in the child component:
<div v-for="(product, index) in filterData" :key="index">

However I can't access it in the childs <script> area to create a new function from the data. Even just trying to console.log(filterData) gives error 'filterData' is not defined.
Here's how I've got it setup:
PARENT
import productData from './assets/products.json'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return{
      productData: productData
    }
  },
}

<template>
  <ChildComponent 
      :productsData="productData" 
      :filterData="productData.products"
    />
</template>

CHILD COMPONENT
<template>
  <div v-for="(product, index) in filterData" :key="index"> // loops fine
    <div class='productName'>{{product.title}}</div>                    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  console.log(filterData) // throws error

  export default {
    name: 'ChildComponent',
    props: {
        productsData: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },
        filterData: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        }
    }
};
</script>

I've tried looking through other questions like this one but they usually discuss what I've already got working, any help on how I get this working?

How are you defining the filterData prop? Won't you need to use this.filterData in the script?

I have tried using the this.filterData just incase but it didn't work, I've just added how the props are defined to the original question.

You can not access props outside of the instance.
If you want to create a function based on the data, use the methods option and refer to the prop as this.filterData.
